# Select few columns in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to entity framework. My table is having more than 20 columns. But sometimes, I need only 2-3 columns from it. Is it a good practice to bring entire rows as Model class object or just use a LINQ to Entity query? Can you please give occasions to choose the best method?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return what you need using a .Select() operation. This can significantly improve performance by making the query quicker and reducing the amount of data coming across the wire from the database server.

Comment: to add to this (perfectly fine) answer: remember to use .Select BEFORE executing the query by enumerating the IQueryable.

Comment: Yes, not much worse than seeing .ToList().Select(x=> ...)  :)

Comment: Thanks for all your replies